# Why are my struct symbols not loading into VS debugger unless I declare a global instance?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, debugging, struct

I have declared a struct in a header file like so:

```
struct NetClient
{
    /* ... */
};
```

I then use this struct to declare a member inside another struct in a different header file like so:

```
struct AppState
{
    /* ... */
    NetClient netClient;
    /* ... */
};
```

For some reason, when I stop the debugger to examine the contents of an instance of `AppState`, I CAN'T examine the contents of `appState->netClient` UNLESS I do the following:

```
struct NetClient
{
    /* ... */
} for_some_reason_declaring_this_global_variable_lets_me_examine_netClient_symbols;
```

What in the world could be causing this??
Additional details:

- I'm compiling using cl.exe
- This code is being compiled into a DLL and loaded dynamically into another program at runtime.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please provide the relevant code to call these two structures? This will help solve the problem.